# Hadoop 2.8 Not opening any TCP Ports

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, odroid

I installed Hadoop 2.8 onto a Odroid XU4 Armhf device running Ubuntu 16.04 Server Edition with OpenJDK 7, by following this Apache guide: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Everything seems okay, when I run jps I see the following processes:

```
- NameNode
- DataNode
- SecondaryNameNode
- ResourceManager
- NodeManager
```

At the moment I have Hadoop setup as a single node cluster, but when I run the command "netstat --listen" I don't see any ports open the Hadoop uses. So port 9000 isn't open, or 50070. Here is what I see from netstat:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:domain        *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:domain        *:*
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*
udp        0      0 *:48076                 *:*
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7
```

When I run start-dfs.sh I see the following output:

```
17/04/28 19:03:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /root/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-odroid1.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /root/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-odroid1.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /root/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-odroid1.out
17/04/28 19:04:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I have spent the last three days debugging this, but for some reason Hadoop isn't opening up any TCP Ports, at all. Is there something I am missing?

I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you able to access HDFS thru commands? What does `hdfs dfs -ls /` return?

Comment: I tried that command it it spit out an error saying it can't connect to port 9000 on localhost, here is the output from the command:

`17/04/28 22:12:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/28 22:12:30 WARN ipc.Client: Failed to connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000: try once and fail.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

And then a bunch of stack trace code was outputted after that.

Comment: @franklinsijo forgot to tag you.

Comment: Are you services still listed when you run `jps`? Can you check for ERRORs in `/root/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-odroid1.log`.

Comment: @franklinsijo The file contains, `2017-04-30 05:51:45,166 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
2017-04-30 05:51:45,197 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-04-30 05:51:45,220 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: createNameNode []`

Comment: Can you scroll to the end to check for errors?

Comment: @franklinsijo That's all that is in that file. There is no errors that I can see from what I posted above. The log file was super short.